# How to remove lingering /etc/openvpn/ directory after removing OpenVPN package?

Tags: openvpn

I want to completely remove openvpn from my pc (Linux Ubuntu 12.04) but when I type

```
sudo apt-get remove  openvpn
```

the `/etc/openvpn/` folder remains... How can I delete this too?

I want to delete openvpn so I can install it again because I think I did something stupid the first time :/

- Do you know how to complete remove it?
- Can you recommend me a good detailed tutorial about installing openvpn in ubuntu 12.10 and how to make certificates?

Answer (score 4):

You can't purge it after you remove it that's why it didn't work

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn && sudo apt-get purge openvpn
```

and yes you can remove it manually (as you seem to have already figured out), see these files as well

**/usr/lib/openvpn**

**/usr/include/openvpn**

**/usr/share/openvpn**

**/usr/share/man/man8/openvpn.8.gz**

To see what files get installed with a package, you can usually run the `whereis` command to see what goes along with it.

example:

```
whereis openvpn
```

example output:

```
openvpn: /usr/sbin/openvpn /etc/openvpn /usr/lib/openvpn /usr/include/openvpn     
/usr/share/openvpn /usr/share/man/man8/openvpn.8.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Config is not deleted by a simple `apt-get remove`.

You want `apt-get purge <package>`.

Comment: i try sudo apt-get purge openvpn    still nothing.

Comment: You may have to just delete that folder manually as well. Some packages to do not have the `purge` argument correctly configured, or will still save their configs for certain reasons.

Comment: i cant delete it manually :/

Comment: Don't forget sudo...

Answer (score 2):

ok problem solved just type

```
cd /etc/
sudo rm -rf openvpn
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way is

```
sudo dpkg -r openvpn-as
```

Comment: That would simply uninstall the package, which the OP has done. You are perhaps thinking of -P ? The man page lists that as Purge, which *DOES* remove the lot.

Comment: i installed openvpn, used it for awhile and uninstall that way. all the folders mentioned by OP is removed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Fabby Actually, this is an answer - the question is "How to remove lingering `/etc/openvpn/` directory - this attempts to provide an answer and is valid.

Comment: @ThomasW. IMHO not really. The OP *should* have done a purge, but alas doing a purge after the fact is impossible so a `sudo rm -rf /etc/openvpn/` is the correct answer, but he already figured that out him/her/itself before this answer. ;-)

Comment: @Fabby It's still an answer attempt albeit not a good one.  It therefore does not fall under the 'Not an Answer' classification.

Comment: @ThomasW. OK. I bow to your wisdom... (All flags already removed, and I'll *really* try to remember, as contrarily to you, I *am* having something nice... A bit too much nice I'm afraid)  ;-)